# Webpack 4 config not picking index.js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

Im doing something silly here. I am using Webpack 4 & trying to run a React app.

I get the html file rendered, however, webpack doesn't show the content of index.js file on browser. I have checked the prod. build & it does contain the react `<hello />` component code, however, it doesn't show in browser (nor does it show console.log executed within index.js).

Directory structure:

[image]

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const baseConfig = {
   context: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
   entry: "./index.js",
   output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
      publicPath: "/",
      filename: "[name].js"
   },
   module: {
      rules: [
         {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: "babel-loader"
         }
      ]
   },
   plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
         template: "./index.html",
         filename: "../build/index.html",
      })
   ]
};

const devConfig = {
   mode: "development",
   devtool: "source-map",
   devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: true,
      hot: true,
      compress: false,
      port: 1111,
      publicPath: "http://localhost:1111/"
   }
};
module.exports = (env, argv) => {
   if (argv.mode === "development") {
      return merge(baseConfig, devConfig);
   }
   return merge(baseConfig, prodConfig);
};
```

index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store";
import Hello from "./components/Hello"; // temp

const initialiseApp = () => {
   const appContainer = document.getElementById("app");
   console.log("hello");
   render(
      <Provider store={store}>
         <Hello />
      </Provider>,
      appContainer
   );
};

initialiseApp();
```

Thanks,

Comment: Try removing context and explicitly pointing to: `entry: 'src/index.js'`;

Comment: I removed `context` & changed entry to `./src/index.js` along with the htmlwebpackmodule path references. However, now I get error: `cannot get /`. In console 3 errors such as: `Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at self...`